# Which ER-model notation does Elasticsearch default to?

Tags: elasticsearch

As asked in the title I'd like to know which ER-model notation Elasticsearch defaults to.
In terms of context, I've received a database schema which I cannot openly share, but the following screenshot shows one of the obscure looking relations.

[image: An obscure looking relation, is this Crow's Foot Notation or something else?]

After a few quick Google searches I was surprised at the fact that I couldn't find any official statement about Elasticsearch's default notation. While searching I came across this post where the OP showed a similar screenshot, but without the obscure double-dashed-line notation: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/convert-relational-schema-to-elasticsearch-mapping/72291

Is this Crow's Foot Notation, or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there's no official model notation that is used for Elasticsearch, so it'd come down to whatever the tool that built this uses